# Can old (pre 1.12) Minecraft structure blocks be transferred to newer versions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have saved some structures to structure blocks in version 1.12.1.

Will the structures load correctly if I transfer those blocks to a newer version 1.20.1?

Answer (score 9):

In Minecraft 1.13, the structure and IDs of many blocks were changed, in what is known as [The Flattening](https://minecraft.wiki/wiki/Java_Edition_1.13/Flattening).

Unfortunately, structure blocks from before this version do not get converted. Per [the History section](https://minecraft.wiki/wiki/Structure_Block#History) on the Minecraft wiki article for Structure Blocks, when loading pre-1.13 structure blocks in a post-1.13 world, it will not load in any blocks whose internal ID has changed.

Comment: The history of the world save file is pretty interesting: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Region_file_format McRegion was editable with McEdit which has long faded away